# Problems debugging a PowerShell cmdlet

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 64-bit Professional. I'm having trouble debugging a custom PowerShell cmdlet.

### Configuration

- Language: C#, targeting .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.
- Platform target: Any CPU
- Start Action: `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
- Command line arguments: `-noexit -command Add-PSSnapIn MyCustomSnapIn`

**Problem 1:** Failure to attach when I press F5 (Debug → Start Debugging)

- PowerShell opens, and Task Manager indicates that powershell.exe is running as a 64-bit process. The Image Path Name column shows the same executable specified in the Start Action.
- If I choose Debug → Break All in Visual Studio, I receive a message "Unable to break execution. This process is not currently executing the type of code that you selected to debug."

**Problem 2:** Unexpectedly launches as a 32-bit process when I press Ctrl+F5 (Debug → Start Without Debugging)

- PowerShell opens. Task Manager indicates that powershell.exe is running as a 32-bit process - this time the Image Path Name shows a SysWOW64 redirection.

**The annoying way to debug right now:** The only way I've found to debug my cmdlet is to press F5, then select Debug→Detach All, then select Debug→Attach To Process and reattach Visual Studio.

Comment: I think you might want to use the `Image Path Name` column in Task Manager if you want to see the *actual* EXE path when OS redirection is involved.

Comment: @Keith Hill: Thanks, I edited to indicate there is no redirection for #1, but there is redirection for #2.

Comment: @SamHarwell: Did you already solved this problem on VS 2017? I am having this problem for VS 15.7.5, but the said "Annoying Way" at least solved my problem, but is there a way to actually not do the "Annoying Way"?

Answer (score 6):

Problem 1:

Seems to me like a bug in VS2010 reported here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/539389/debugging-powershell-cmdlet-from-vs-2010-does-not-stop-at-breakpoints?wa=wsignin1.0

Using VS2008 should help.

Update:
I found **more convenient way to debug powershell cmdlets**. In the solution explorer right click on solution node -> Add -> New project -> Select powershell.exe file (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe). Set newly added project as start up project (right click and select "Set As Startup Project"). Then go to project properties (right click on project node and select "Properties") and set the "Debugger Type" property to "Managed (v2.0, v1.1, v1.0)". Don't forget to register your Provider or CmdLet (by running post build events, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714644%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Now, the program should stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: +1 - this is indeed exactly the issue, thanks for digging it up; unfortunately nobody seems to feel responsible there right now because they failed to understand the initial bug report (and subsequent comments). Maybe someone with a direct contact at Microsoft could bump this again?

Comment: I added a comment, clarifying the repro case. It seems my question here should really clear up the confusion between whoever tested it at MS and the people experiencing it.

Answer (score 2):

On problem #2, since Visual Studio is a 32-bit process running on WOW64, the path `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` is redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`. Which is where the 32-bit version of PowerShell lives.

Comment: As I mentioned, the actual path launched was verified by Task Manager to be under `system32`, *not* under `SysWOW64`.

Comment: @280z28 i think you're missing the subtle point that yes, the launch path is system32 but windows (not powershell or vs) redirects the request to syswo64, silently and transparently.

Comment: @280Z28 - Are you looking at the "Command Line" column or the "Image Path Name" column?  Cuz when I try this experiment in VS 2010, Ctrl+F5 fires up command line `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` but Image Path Name says `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this posting is about a year old at this point, but it may help someone else struggling with this anyway.

I have found that the following scenario works for me with PowerShell 2.0. I am also using VS2010 SP1 on Windows 7 64-bit.

With PS 2.0 you **no longer** have to install cmdlets using **installutil**. Instead you can use `Import-Module` instead (which does **not** require Admin rights). I will not go into full detail on how that is done as a web search will reveal most details, but in short, you will need to create a folder (if it does not already exist) at:

```
md (Join-Path (Split-Path $profile) modules)
```

Under the modules folder, create another folder with the same name as your cmdlet DLL (minus “.DLL”). This folder will contain your binary and a psd1 file that describes your DLL (see [Module Manifests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878337%28VS.85%29.aspx)).  For my convenience I created this folder as a folder symbolic link to my project’s bin\debug folder.

You still need to run PowerShell (or PowerShell ISE) from Visual Studio as describe elsewhere in the “Start Action” section of the Debug tab of your project properties.

Set your breakpoints and go. Once PowerShell starts, type:

```
Import-Module <ModuleName>
```

Then run your cmdlet.

---

#### Sample

```
C:\Users\<me>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\modules\MyCmdlet\MyCmdlet.dll 
C:\Users\<me>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\modules\MyCmdlet\MyCmdlet.pdb
C:\Users\<me>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\modules\MyCmdlet\MyCmdlet.psd1
C:\Users\<me>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\modules\MyCmdlet\MyCmdlet.Types.ps1xml (etc.)
```

In PowerShell type (can be put in your profile too):

```
Import-Module MyCmdlet
```

For me, this hits all my breakpoints and also stops on exceptions. All without having to attach to a process, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1: powershell.exe is not actually a managed executable. It hosts the CLR itself, so you need to enable native code debugging alongside managed for this to work.

As for problem 2, I'm not sure about this. Obviously VS itself is a 32bit process so perhaps it's interfering here.

Comment: Regarding #1: Visual Studio (devenv.exe) is also not a managed executable, but you don't have to enable native code debugging for the debugger to correctly work with managed code add-ins. Regarding #2: Visual Studio has no trouble debugging other 64-bit binaries. This is the first issue I've run into.

Comment: @280z28, yes but are these 64bit binaries in %systemroot%?

Comment: Try using the special %windir%\sysnative path to launch powershell, e.g. launch path of %windir%\sysnative\windowspowershell\1.0\powershell.exe to see if this supresses the redirect.

Comment: You can't use the sysnative special folder in the Start Action in Visual Studio. It gives a message that the system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve problem #2 by creating the folder `C:\dev\PowerShell\x64` and copying everything from `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` into it. I created a similar folder `C:\dev\PowerShell\x86`. The intended version of PowerShell always launches when I specify these paths, so the shortest way to start debugging is now Start Without Debugging followed by Attach To Process.

Comment: so you understand now that this is a windows system32 redirect, not some powershell quirk, right?

Comment: @x0n: Yes, but it still doesn't allow me to debug the code through a direct launch. I have to use Attach To Process.

Comment: You could also hoist the scripts into  system.management.automation in a peer project as a debugging host. Creating runspaces and testing cmdlets like this can be a lot easier than tinkering with the full shell. I blogged the guts of what you'd need: http://www.nivot.org/2010/05/03/PowerShell20DeveloperEssentials1InitializingARunspaceWithAModule.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how you're installing the plugin before calling Add-PSSnapin to make it usable in your debugging session.

Make sure that you are installing the plugin using `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe`, and not the one in ...\Framework... - this stumped me for a couple days.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with VS2010, but it went away after installing SP1.